# How to initialize and inject dependency like RpcClient?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I'm initializing an `RPCClient` in the Inversify container:

container.ts:

```
....
container.bind<IRPCClient>(TYPES.RPCClient).to(RPCClient);
....
```

In `main.ts` I'm initializing this RPCClient:

```
...
container.get<IRPCClient>(TYPES.RPCClient).initialize({ serviceName: ServiceName.IMA, url: imaRpcUrl });
...
```

Then how can I inject the initialized instance from `main.ts` to interactors/services with the `@inject` annotation?

When I inject the RPCClient from the container, I'm getting the uninitialized instance...

What should I do?

Thanks!